# Is there a shortcut to copy a method to the interface?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I rather like the "Extract Interface..." refactoring function when working on a class, but it only allows you to extract to a new interface. I was wondering if there was a similar option that allowed the user to copy a method(s) to an interface(s) that the current class already implements.

It's something that would save me a lot of time but despite thinking I may have done something like that before, I can't find any reference to such a function. Does anyone know if it even exists?

Comment: I don't use NetBeans, but other IDEs call this refactoring "pull up method" -- see if that option is available.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Indeed there is! Thank you~ write your comment as an answer and I'll upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refactoring is called "pull up method." You can move a method to a superclass, or add its declaration to any of the interfaces a class implements.